# Role of square brackets

Tags: r

I got this code from elsewhere and I wondering if someone can explain what the square brackets are doing.

```
matrix1[i,] <- df[[1]][]
```

I am using this to assign values to a matrix and it works but I am not sure what exactly it's doing. What does the initial set of [[]] mean followed by another []?

Comment: you can find the help for the extractors by typing `?\`[\`` on the console

Comment: That brackets are a generic operator jn R. They can do different things for different object types. You need to provide a reproducible example so we can say for sure what’s going on. It’s very difficult to answer for all possible uses of []. It depends on how your data is structured.

Comment: Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you understand a bit. You can copy and paste this code and see the differences between different ways of indexing using [] and $. The only thing I can't answer for you is the second empty set of square brackets, from my understanding that does nothing, unless a value is within those brackets.

```
#Retreives the first column as a data frame
mtcars[1]

#Retrieves the first column values only (three different methods of doing the same thing)
mtcars[,1]
mtcars[[1]]
mtcars$mpg

#Retrieves the first row as a data frame
mtcars[1,]

#I can use a second set of brackets to get the 4th value within the first column
mtcars[[1]][4]
mtcars$mpg[4]
```

Comment: This was very clear thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The general function of `[` is that of subsetting, which is well documented both in help (as suggested in comments), and in [this piece](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html). The rest of of my answer is heavily based on that source.

In fact, there are operators for subsetting in R; `[[`,`[`, and `$`.
The `[` and `$` are useful for returning the index and named position, respectfully, for example the first three elements of vector `a = 1:10` may be subsetted with `a[c(1,2,3)]`. You can also negatively subset to remove elements, as `a[-1]` will remove the first index.

The `$` operator is different in that it only takes element names as input, e.g. if your `df` was a dataframe with a column `values`, `df$values` would subset that column. You can achieve the same `[`, but only with a quoted name such as `df["values"]`.

To answer more specifically, what does `df[[1]][]` do?
First, the `[[`-operator will return the 1st element from `df`, and the following empty `[`-operator will pull everything from that output.

Comment: I believe you need to do `?\`[\`` to see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Baraliuh, that's entirely correct.